# GitHub pages "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."

Tags: github, dns, cloudflare, cname

TL;DR: Changed my GH-Pages domain to a custom one, the custom one works well but the default (old) one is not redirecting to the custom one.

I have a GitHub pages repo that was on [the default domain](https://mohamed3on.github.io), then switched it to a [custom domain](https://mohamed3on.online), which worked fine, and the default domain was redirecting to the new one. I then changed the repo's name to the new domain's name, but when I went to the old domain, it returned 404, so I changed the repo's name back to the default one (mohamed3on.github.io), but it still returns 404 and says

> There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

The [repo](https://github.com/Mohamed3on/Mohamed3on.github.io) contains a `CNAME` with `mohamed3on.online`.
What do you think I should change?

Comment: It's working fine

Comment: @A.Raza indeed, seems to take time to update, perhaps changing the repo's name broke it? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have been included **`CNAME`** in the root directory.

Comment: I am so glad this question was asked and had an answer. I'm sure this procedure is readily present in the docs, but I overlooked it, so I am glad SO has a question and answer for why I see "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."